# Div extended past container div using negative margins has x scrolling only when connected to TV via HDMI cable

Tags: html, css, extend, horizontal-scrolling, hdmi

I am currently working on a company website. I've used negative margins plus positive padding to make the footer and top bars fill the 100% width of the page even though they are contained within another div, the wrapper set at about 65%. This is, as far as I know, a relatively well known way to do it but causes that content to go beyond the sides of the page.

Anyway, in order to prevent sideways scrolling there's x-overflow: hidden on both the html and body. This works when I'm at my computer but when I was showing the website to my coworkers today it was not working. I had my laptop connected to a large TV through an HDMI cable and I was able to scroll to the side (no scroll bar, just able to with a three button mouse). Went back to my normal setup (same laptop with a second monitor attached) and I can no longer scroll.

Code is something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="extend">
  This is the div extending beyond the page and causing sideways scroll. 
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.extend {
 padding-left:35%;
 margin-left:-35%;
 padding-right:35%;
 margin-right:-35%;
}

 #wrapper {
 width:65%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

This isn't a super huge issue for me (unless I discover it happens in more cases). I doubt my website will be viewed that often on a large TV connected to a laptop but I am curious as to what's causing it. Or if anyone has any better ways of extending divs past their containers, I'd be willing to hear about those too. Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Please try to correct `x-overflow` to `overflow-x`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. :) Just realized. I didn't actually copy this from my website, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Would you consider a structure change to your html?

Comment: I would. Depends on what you'd like to suggest of course.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
 width:65%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.extend {
 /* 35/65*100 = 26.92 */
 margin-right:-26.92%; 
 margin-left:-26.92%;

 background-color: red;
}
.extent-content {
 width:100%;
 padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Full width example</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div class="extend">
      <div class="extent-content">
       This is the div extending beyond the page and causing sideways scroll. 
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a structure that has an outer wrapper and inner wrapper per section. The inner wrapper will get the fixed width and the outer typically gets 100% of the screen. This allows you to have full width sections and contained sections together without using negative margins.

Fiddle with example:
http://jsfiddle.net/h0k5pape/2/

Code style:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```